# Run a flash movie in flex application

Tags: apache-flex, flash, movieclip

I've a flash movie that I would like to use inside of a flex application, very similar to a preloader.

Looking at this tutorial, http://www.flexer.info/2008/02/07/very-first-flex-preloader-customization/, I expected it would be a matter of not extending "Preloader" and extending "Sprite" and using the class i created wherever i needed.

Alas, the movie I created, is not being shown.

This is the code for my class containing the movie, made based on the tutorial above:

```
package 
{
    import mx.preloaders.DownloadProgressBar;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class PlayerAnimation extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed("Player.swf")]
        public var PlayerGraphic:Class;

        public var mc:MovieClip;

        public function PlayerAnimation():void
        {
            super();
            mc = new PlayerGraphic();
            addChild(mc);
        }

        public function Play():void
        {
            mc.gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to take into account that flex's basic display primitive is UIComponent, as opposed to Flash that uses mainly Sprites. You can only add a UIComponent to a Flex component (and not directly a Sprite, as you seem to be trying to do).

you should:

var iui:UIComponent=new UIComponent();
//first create the UIComponent container
var player:PlayerAnimation=new PlayerAnimation();
//then create your Sprite-based class
player.width=this.width;
player.height=this.height;
//set-up height,width
iui.addChild(player);
//add your Sprite-based class to the UIComponent
this.addChild(iui);
//finally you can add the UIComponent to your Flex Container (Application, TitleWindow, VBox, Panel... whatever it is)